# InheritanceType.JOINED. mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

I need `FruitBasket` deep copy with full hierarchy for persistence with new id's. I'm trying to map entities with such a hierarchy.

When I try to load the FruitBasket entity I get this error:

> `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: Apple.fruitBasket in FruitBasket.apples`.

Here is what I tried:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "FRUIT")
public class Fruit implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "FRUIT_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FRUIT_BASKET_ID")
    private FruitBasket fruitBasket;

    // additional fields are insignificant

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public FruitBasket getFruitBasket() {
        return fruitBasket;
    }

    public void setFruitBasket(FruitBasket fruitBasket) {
        this.fruitBasket = fruitBasket;
    }

    public <T extends Fruit> T copy(Class<T> clazz) {
        T fruit;
        try {
            fruit = clazz.newInstance();
        } 
        catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return fruit;
    }

}
```

---

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "APPLE")
public class Apple extends Fruit {

    // additional fields are insignificant
    // copy apple
    public Apple copy() {           
        // copy logic
        return super.copy(getClass());
    }    
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PEAR")
public class Pear extends Fruit {

    // additional fields are insignificant

    // copy pear
   public Pear copy() {

       return super.copy(getClass());
   }

}
```

---

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

@Entity
@Table(name = "FRUIT_BASKET")
public class FruitBasket implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "FRUIT_BASKET_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fruitBasket")
    private Collection<Apple> apples = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fruitBasket")
    private Collection<Pear> pears = new ArrayList<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Collection<Apple> getApples() {
       return apples;
    }

    public void setApples(Collection<Apple> apples) {
       this.apples = apples;
    }

   public Collection<Pear> getPears() {
        return pears;
   }

    public void setPears(Collection<Pear> pears) {
        this.pears = pears;
    }

    public void addApple(Apple apple) {
        apple.setFruitBasket(this);
        apples.add(apple);
    }

    public void addPear(Pear pear) {
        pear.setFruitBasket(this);
        pears.add(pear);
    }

    public FruitBasket copy() {
        FruitBasket newFruitBasket = new FruitBasket();

        for (Apple apple : apples) {
            newFruitBasket.addApple(apple.copy());
        }

        for (Pear pear : pears) {
            newFruitBasket.addPear(pear.copy());
        }

        return newFruitBasket;
    }
}
```

I need just to find FruitBasket copy it and save.

***RESOLVED. It will not work. For more info see link above***
http://chriswongdevblog.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/polymorphic-one-to-many-relationships.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a polymorphic association in your FruitBasket entity like this

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "fruitBasket")
    private Collection<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<>();
```

and not :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "fruitBasket")
    private Collection<Apple> apples = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "fruitBasket")
    private Collection<Pear> pears = new ArrayList<>();
```

it should work !

for example you want to get an Apple

```
Fruit fruit = session.get(Fruit.class, fruitId);

if(fruit instanceOf Apple) Apple apple = (Apple) fruit
```

Comment: But I need additional information from Apple and Pear. This classes contain diff information. How I can do this with such proposal?

Comment: Just cast the fruit fetched from the database, something like: if(fruit instanceOf Apple) ...

Comment: Thank you. But I think I don't fully laid out the essence of the problem. I've updated the post